# How do I create guest sudo privilege for unique python script?

Tags: linux, permissions

On Raspberry Pi I want a guest user to be able to run a single python script that requires sudo privileges but nothing else that requires sudo privileges without use of a password.

I have edited the /etc/sudoer file using viuser but have not been able to get the result desired.  When I log in as 'guest' and try to run the script the computer asks for a superuser password.

The edited /etc/sudoer file follows:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        
secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification
User_Alias      GROUPONE = guest

# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias      SCRIPT = /home/guest/test.py
GROUPONE        ALL = SCRIPT

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
GROUPONE    ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/guest/test.py

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

The python script is:

```
import subprocess
def Go():
    subprocess.call(['sudo','echo', 'Test string'])
if __name == '__main__':
    Go()
```

Expected result of 'python test.py' is 'Test string' on the console.
Instead the computer requests the guest sudo password.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try

```
modify user <GUEST> to add additional group <sudo>, I think <usermod --group GRP1...>

change group of the script to <sudo> and make group executable <chmod g+x SCRIPT> & < chgrp sudo SCRIPT>
```

I havent tested it but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

This edit of /etc/sudoers via visudo did the trick.  'guest' can execute either python script or bash script that calls the python script as root without needing password, but nothing else at all, since no 'guest' password was assigned.

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification    

# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias USER_CMDS = /usr/bash, /usr/bin/python, /home/guest/test.py,\
 /home/guest/test_pi.sh


# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
guest   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: USER_CMDS

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```